# Is it possible to use Knockout Observables within D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, knockout.js

I've got a Single Page Application that I'm building that uses a combination of `D3` and `Knockout`. Currently they're doing separate jobs and handling their own data-binding, but there is a little bit of crossover that we have to handle.

This got me thinking, and it'd be great if this crossover could just be handled automagically and `Knockout` and `D3` were to play nicely together. Here's a couple of brief examples on what I'd like to do:

#### Binding a Single Value

In this case I've got a single text item and I want to directly bind the value to my observable

```
d3.select("text").text(myObservable);
```

#### Binding Multiple Values

In this case I've got many text items and want to bind to the observable that resides on the data element:

```
d3.select("text").text(function(d) { return d.myObservable(); });
```

#### Binding Single Value with a Function (and Transition)

This is a cross between both cases (but I think is similar to binding to multiple values) in that I've got a single item now, but I need to be able to execute a function to grab my value properly. Here if the observable were to change this would fire the animation to change the stroke style.

```
d3.select("path")
  .style("stroke", "white")
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .style("stroke", function(d) { 
    var value = d.myObservable();
    if(value < 0) return "red";
    if(value === 0) return "orange";
    return "green";
});
```

---

As far as solutions go, I was playing with the idea of overriding the `d3.selection.prototype.text` function (and probably a whole load of others) along the lines of:

```
var setText = d3.selection.prototype.setText;
d3.selection.prototype.setText = function(value, index, groupIndex) {

    var selection = this;
    if(value && ko.isObservable(value)) {
       value.subscribe(function() {
          setText.call(selection, value(), index, groupIndex);
       });
       setText.call(selection, value(), index, groupIndex);
       return;
    }

    if(typeof value === function) {
        var result = value();

        // Not sure how to achieve this bit
        if(value used an observable) {
           allObservablesUsedInFunction.subscribe(function() {
              result = value();
              setText.call(selection, value(), index, groupIndex);
           });
        }

        setText.call(selection, result, index, groupIndex);
        return;
    }

    setText.call(selection, value, index, groupIndex);
};
```

I'm not sure how I monitor observables used within a function though, or how to get them for the subscription afterwards. My gut feeling is also that I'm going to struggle firing off the `d3.transition()` on that stroke that I'd really like. So I'm wondering if there are any other ways I might achieve the affect I want?

I have briefly considered a subscription on any changes - that would trigger a typical `D3` update operation - but some of my animations need to fire only if a value has changed since the last update, and I'm not sure how I'd be able to determine that. For example - I don't want the stroke transition to fire if the current observable value is the same as the previous one (red->white->red would look silly).

Comment: Have you seen this? http://jsfiddle.net/milimetric/ug9x8/89/

Comment: @RoyJ That looks a little like my final paragraph - triggering an update when a higher level subscription changed. If you were to try modifying an item in the data table you'll find the graphs don't update. So you need to start listening to the sub-observables too. If I could solve how my stroke transition works (only animating if an observable actually changed) then that approach may has some merit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the caveat that my understanding of d3 is about the same as a newborn kitten's, I'll give you half an answer now and hopefully I'll have some time to make it more substantial later.

Since d3 is a DOM-oriented package, the way to use it with Knockout is to relegate it to [custom binding handlers](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html). That is where DOM manipulations go. That will effectively give you a subscription to the relevant observables, and you shouldn't have to hybridize d3's prototypes.

For your color-change example, I think if you made a computed to return the color value, and subscribed to that computed, your subscription wouldn't fire if the color didn't actually change.

**Update:**
I've written a somewhat generic "d3" binding handler for you. It takes as parameters a `script` and `options` for that script. The script should take a a d3 object (which the binding handler will construct from the element it's bound to) and an `options` object. The binding handler unwraps any observables in the `options` so that the script sees plain values.

For the example here, I've bound it to a path element and supplied the color-changing script from your question. Because I used a computed to determine the color, you can see there are no transitions when the color doesn't actually change.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.d3 = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
    var d3element = d3.select(element),
      params = valueAccessor();
    for (opt in params.options) {
      params.options[opt] = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(params.options[opt]);
    }
    params.script(d3element, params.options);
  }

};

vm = (function() {
  var v = ko.observable(3),
    color = ko.computed(function() {
      if (v() < 0) return 'red';
      if (v() === 0) return 'orange';
      return 'green';
    });
  return {
    v: v,
    color: color,
    d3script: function(d3element, options) {
      d3element.style("stroke", "black")
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .style("stroke", options.color);
    },
    decrement: function() {
      v(v() - 1);
    },
    increment: function() {
      v(v() + 1);
    }

  };
}());

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<button data-bind="click:decrement">-</button>
<span data-bind="text:v"></span>

<button data-bind="click:increment">+</button>
<svg width="4cm" height="4cm" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <title>Example triangle01- simple example of a 'path'</title>
  <desc>A path that draws a triangle</desc>
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="398" height="398" fill="none" stroke="blue" />
  <path data-bind="d3:{script: d3script, options: {color:color}}" d="M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z" fill="#fdd" stroke="blue" stroke-width="7" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks Roy, will be interested to hear you ellaborate. I'm using a few custom binding handlers already and I have a feeling that I won't be able to quite achieve what I want with them (because really I can only apply 1 custom binding handler - unless I generate and re-bind the DOM to Knockout within D3). I've also found in the one instance that I generate SVG using Knockout for a fairly simple case, I had to use 5 custom bindings to achieve the animation affects I wanted - which felt a bit over the top.